# PyPlot double x-axis with correlated ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a fast way to add a second x-axis with ticks correlated to the primary x-axis using Plot from Matplotlib?

My source data is in amplitude per sample where each sample corresponds to 100 ns and I would like to have both (sample-no and time) in my plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a secondary `x-axis/y-axis` using the function [twiny and twinx](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) accordingly.

Here is a sample code with **correlated** `x-axis` ticks. The bottom being the primary and the top being the secondary.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

a = np.sin(np.pi*np.linspace(0, 1, 60.))

ax1.plot(range(60), a)
ax2.plot(range(60), np.ones(60)) # Create a dummy plot
ax1.set_xlabel('$primary\/x\/axis$')
ax2.set_xlabel('$secondary\/x\/axis$')
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]